# is it is correct to mention PhD in brackets or with upper line to express ongoing degree.(PhD) ̅

Tags: expressions

is it is correct to write PhD as suffix in brackets or with upperline to express the degree is ongoing. is there any reference for this type of expressions

Answer (score 2):

One either has the degree, or one has not.

For a person who is about to go through the ceremony, the term **graduand** exists:

> graduand (noun)  ​(UK, Canada)
>
> A student who has completed the requirements for, but has not yet been
>   awarded, a particular degree.   A rather specialized term: since
>   degrees are generally awarded shortly after requirements have been
>   completed, this is generally a very short-term status (weeks to
>   months), quickly changing to graduate. Primarily used to refer to
>   students at graduation ceremonies (as in the quote above), in Britain
>   and similar Commonwealth school systems (Australia, Canada, Hong Kong,
>   Malaysia, Namibia, Singapore). It has important legal implications for
>   certain disciplines; for example, medical graduands are able to be
>   registered to practise, and commence work as junior medical officers,
>   before officially graduating at a ceremony which may occur some six
>   months later.
>
> In the US, the general term *student* is generally used instead.

[[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graduand)]

With regard to use of the *'title'-or-is-it-yet?* , at [St John's College, Cambridge](http://www.joh.cam.ac.uk/graduation-faqs#faq11), at least, graduation is the passport:

> Can I use my ‘title’ even if the relevant degree hasn’t yet been
>   conferred on me?

...

> *No. Your degree must be conferred on you at a ceremony before you can use the title.*

I would expect this to be the norm.

Comment: Edwin, you might want to correct the spelling of your source. It should be "Wiktionary".

Comment: I must have been subkonsciously wishing for a more respected sourke. Actually, I was concentrating on when it becomes acceptable to assume the letters after one's name. This is a matter of establishment protocol rather than English, though.